# R ggplot - create multiple panels in a chart with data from more than one data frame

Tags: r, dataframe, ggplot2

Given data like below

```
text1 <- "
Time,Col01,Col02,Col03,Col04,Col05,Col06,Col07,Col08,Col09,Col10,Col11,Col12
05:17:55.703000,268,4,28,-67.69999999999999,12.5,21.0,2.0,3.0,177.66666666666666,892,18,1.5
05:17:55.743000,268,4,28,-67.475,12.5,20.0,2.0,3.0,211.94736842105263,896,17,2.0
05:17:55.783000,268,4,28,-67.58,12.5,20.0,2.0,3.0,144.55555555555554,902,18,1.5
05:17:55.823000,268,4,28,-67.26,12.5,20.0,2.0,3.0,150.5,906,18,1.5
05:17:55.863000,268,4,28,-67.135,12.5,20.0,2.0,3.0,138.5609756097561,908,18,1.5
05:17:55.903000,268,4,28,-67.96000000000001,13.0,21.0,2.0,3.0,130.6,914,17,2.0
05:17:55.943000,268,4,28,-67.33500000000001,10.5,14.0,2.5,4.0,161.71428571428572,917,17,2.5
05:17:55.983000,268,4,28,-67.555,11.5,17.0,2.5,3.0,121.2258064516129,920,17,2.0
05:17:56.023000,268,4,28,-67.70500000000001,11.5,22.0,2.5,3.0,137.71875,927,18,2.5
05:17:56.063000,,,,,,22.0,,3.0,174.95348837209303,929,18,
05:17:56.103000,,,,,,14.0,,4.0,193.0,933,18,
05:17:56.143000,268,4,28,-67.49,12.0,16.0,3.0,4.0,164.58620689655172,938,18,3.0
05:17:56.183000,268,4,,-67.41,,23.0,,3.0,144.10714285714286,943,18,
05:17:56.223000,,,28,,13.0,16.0,2.0,4.0,141.30769230769232,946,17,1.0
05:17:56.263000,,,,,,24.0,,3.0,178.77142857142857,949,18,
05:17:56.303000,268,4,28,-67.66,12.0,22.0,2.0,3.0,169.8421052631579,951,18,2.0
05:17:56.343000,268,4,28,-67.75999999999999,12.5,22.0,2.0,3.0,144.10526315789474,956,17,2.0
05:17:56.383000,268,4,28,-67.625,12.0,20.0,2.0,3.0,123.33333333333333,962,13,2.0
05:17:56.423000,268,4,28,-67.57499999999999,12.5,20.0,2.0,3.0,155.44827586206895,964,17,2.0
05:17:56.463000,268,4,28,-67.515,12.5,21.0,2.0,3.0,182.24137931034483,968,18,1.5
05:17:56.503000,268,4,28,-67.35499999999999,14.0,19.0,1.0,3.0,191.9090909090909,972,18,1.0
05:17:56.543000,268,4,28,-67.81,12.0,19.0,2.0,3.0,206.85294117647058,976,18,1.0
05:17:56.583000,268,4,28,-67.68,11.0,19.0,2.0,3.0,180.25925925925927,980,18,1.0
05:17:56.623000,268,4,28,-67.61,10.0,19.5,2.5,3.0,153.875,987,16,2.0
05:17:56.663000,268,4,28,-68.005,11.0,19.0,2.0,3.0,187.4406779661017,988,18,1.0
05:17:56.703000,268,4,28,-67.68,10.5,16.0,2.5,3.0,179.46153846153845,992,17,2.0
05:17:56.743000,268,4,28,-67.575,10.0,14.0,2.5,4.0,154.45454545454547,998,18,2.0
05:17:56.783000,268,4,28,-67.17,11.0,20.0,2.0,3.0,150.26829268292684,1002,18,1.0
05:17:56.823000,268,4,28,-67.41,11.0,20.0,2.0,3.0,174.2093023255814,1006,18,1.5
05:17:56.863000,268,4,28,-67.64,11.0,20.0,2.0,3.0,210.95555555555555,1008,18,1.0
05:17:56.903000,268,4,28,-67.62,11.0,21.0,2.0,3.0,204.9607843137255,1012,18,1.0
05:17:56.943000,268,4,28,-67.33,10.0,20.0,2.0,3.0,186.76923076923077,1015,18,1.0
05:17:56.983000,268,4,28,-67.495,10.0,19.0,2.0,3.0,145.0,1023,10,1.0
05:17:57.023000,268,4,28,-67.345,10.0,19.0,2.0,3.0,164.91489361702128,2,18,1.0
05:17:57.063000,268,4,28,-67.62,11.0,18.0,2.0,3.0,137.3404255319149,6,17,1.0
05:17:57.103000,268,4,28,-67.545,12.0,20.0,2.0,3.0,145.0,9,18,1.0
05:17:57.143000,268,4,28,-67.625,10.0,19.0,2.0,3.0,113.88888888888889,12,18,1.0
05:17:57.183000,268,4,28,-67.63999999999999,10.0,20.0,2.0,3.0,122.71428571428571,17,17,1.0
05:17:57.223000,268,4,28,-67.58500000000001,11.0,20.0,2.0,3.0,211.43478260869566,22,18,1.0
05:17:57.263000,268,4,28,-67.8,10.0,20.0,2.0,3.0,163.13333333333333,24,18,1.0
05:17:57.303000,268,4,28,-67.68,10.0,20.0,2.0,3.0,135.96774193548387,31,18,1.0
05:17:57.343000,268,4,28,-67.775,10.0,20.0,2.0,3.0,153.4,32,18,1.0
05:17:57.383000,268,4,28,-67.645,10.0,21.0,2.0,3.0,122.63157894736842,36,18,1.0
05:17:57.423000,268,4,28,-67.97999999999999,10.0,21.0,2.0,3.0,162.8235294117647,40,18,1.0
05:17:57.463000,268,4,28,-68.11,10.0,21.0,2.0,3.0,142.85365853658536,45,18,1.0
05:17:57.503000,268,4,28,-67.93,12.0,22.0,2.0,3.0,158.43333333333334,49,18,1.0
05:17:57.543000,268,4,28,-67.945,10.0,21.0,2.0,3.0,141.25581395348837,52,18,1.0
05:17:57.583000,268,4,28,-67.8,15.0,22.0,1.0,3.0,137.63888888888889,58,18,1.0
05:17:57.623000,268,4,28,-67.66,10.0,22.0,2.0,3.0,160.775,60,18,1.0
05:17:57.663000,268,4,28,-67.9,12.5,22.0,1.5,3.0,142.59574468085106,65,18,1.0
05:17:57.703000,268,4,28,-67.895,10.0,22.0,2.0,3.0,192.1860465116279,69,18,1.0
05:17:57.743000,268,4,28,-68.045,10.0,22.0,2.0,3.0,155.38297872340425,74,18,1.0
05:17:57.783000,268,4,28,-68.02,10.0,21.0,2.0,3.0,121.0,75,18,1.0
05:17:57.823000,268,4,28,-67.97,10.0,22.0,2.0,3.0,155.77083333333334,81,18,1.0
05:17:57.863000,268,4,28,-67.80000000000001,10.0,21.0,2.0,3.0,153.27272727272728,85,18,1.0
05:17:57.903000,268,4,28,-67.62,10.0,21.0,2.0,3.0,141.72727272727272,89,17,1.0
05:17:57.943000,,,28,,10.0,22.0,2.0,3.0,161.0,91,18,1.0
05:17:57.983000,268,4,28,-67.885,10.0,21.0,2.0,3.0,170.21875,96,18,1.0
05:17:58.023000,268,4,28,-67.905,10.0,21.0,2.0,3.0,153.85714285714286,102,18,1.0
05:17:58.063000,268,4,28,-67.99,10.0,21.0,2.0,3.0,147.66666666666666,104,18,1.0
05:17:58.103000,268,4,28,-67.65,10.0,21.0,2.0,3.0,133.6153846153846,108,18,1.0
05:17:58.143000,268,4,28,-67.47,10.0,21.0,2.0,3.0,156.46511627906978,114,18,1.0
05:17:58.183000,268,4,28,-67.87,10.0,22.0,2.0,3.0,146.86666666666667,118,18,1.0
05:17:58.223000,268,4,28,-67.64,10.0,22.0,2.0,3.0,148.47368421052633,120,18,1.0
05:17:58.263000,268,4,28,-67.725,10.0,22.0,2.0,3.0,128.15384615384616,125,18,1.0
05:17:58.303000,268,4,28,-67.44,10.0,21.0,2.0,3.0,145.3181818181818,130,18,1.0
05:17:58.343000,268,4,28,-67.5,10.0,21.0,2.0,3.0,150.27272727272728,134,18,1.0
05:17:58.383000,268,4,28,-67.485,10.0,20.0,2.0,3.0,174.83673469387756,136,18,1.0
05:17:58.423000,268,4,28,-67.405,10.0,20.0,2.0,3.0,166.17777777777778,140,18,1.0
05:17:58.463000,268,4,28,-67.63,10.0,20.0,2.0,3.0,148.87234042553192,144,18,1.0
05:17:58.503000,268,4,28,-67.57,10.0,20.0,2.0,3.0,124.0,148,17,1.0
05:17:58.543000,268,4,28,-67.35,10.0,20.0,2.0,3.0,148.78947368421052,154,18,1.0
05:17:58.583000,268,4,28,-67.44,10.0,21.0,2.0,3.0,164.63636363636363,156,18,1.0
05:17:58.623000,268,4,28,-67.47,10.0,17.0,2.0,4.0,163.8,161,18,1.0
05:17:58.663000,268,4,28,-67.645,12.5,21.0,1.5,3.0,136.37254901960785,166,18,1.0
05:17:58.703000,268,4,28,-67.35,10.0,21.0,2.0,3.0,136.0681818181818,170,18,1.0
05:17:58.743000,268,4,28,-67.74,10.0,20.0,2.0,3.0,151.67391304347825,173,18,1.0
05:17:58.783000,268,4,28,-67.68,10.0,20.5,2.0,3.0,171.66666666666666,176,18,1.0
05:17:58.823000,268,4,28,-67.83,10.0,21.0,2.0,3.0,163.2051282051282,181,18,1.0
05:17:58.863000,268,4,28,-67.94,10.0,21.0,2.0,3.0,146.87234042553192,185,18,1.0
05:17:58.903000,268,4,28,-67.77,10.0,21.0,2.0,3.0,154.14705882352942,189,17,1.0
05:17:58.943000,268,4,28,-68.035,11.0,22.0,2.0,3.0,174.33333333333334,192,18,1.0
05:17:58.983000,268,4,28,-67.57,12.0,22.0,2.0,3.0,188.54166666666666,196,18,1.0
05:17:59.023000,268,4,28,-67.81,10.0,21.0,2.0,3.0,147.0,203,18,1.0
05:17:59.063000,268,4,28,-67.655,10.0,21.0,2.0,3.0,187.97674418604652,204,18,1.0
05:17:59.103000,268,4,28,-68.15,10.0,21.0,2.0,3.0,149.40816326530611,209,17,1.0
05:17:59.143000,268,4,28,-67.63,10.0,21.0,2.0,3.0,173.91176470588235,213,17,1.0
05:17:59.183000,268,4,28,-67.465,11.0,21.0,2.0,3.0,125.17391304347827,218,17,1.0
05:17:59.223000,268,4,28,-67.48,10.0,21.0,2.0,3.0,167.84444444444443,222,18,1.0
05:17:59.263000,268,4,,-67.08,,21.0,,3.0,146.9375,225,18,
05:17:59.303000,268,4,28,-67.46,10.0,21.0,2.0,3.0,144.60714285714286,228,17,1.0
05:17:59.343000,268,4,28,-67.935,10.0,19.0,2.0,3.0,150.06666666666666,232,18,1.0
05:17:59.383000,268,4,28,-68.32,9.0,19.0,2.5,3.0,168.40740740740742,238,18,2.0
05:17:59.423000,268,4,28,-68.235,10.0,19.0,2.0,3.0,143.2608695652174,242,18,1.0
05:17:59.463000,268,4,28,-68.0,11.0,20.0,2.0,3.0,166.76,244,18,1.0
05:17:59.503000,268,4,28,-67.78,11.0,22.0,2.0,3.0,122.95,248,18,1.0
"
df1 <- read.table(textConnection(text1), sep=",", header = T)
```

Tried the following to create a multi-panel chart with common x-axis as column `Time` with one panel for each of the rest of the columns from `Col01:Col12`

```
df1$Time2 = as.POSIXct(df1$Time, format = "%H:%M:%OS") # proper time object
df1 = df1[, -c(1)] # drop Time Column

df1_long = gather(df1, key, value, c(1:12)) # drop Time col
df1_long = df1_long %>%
  arrange(Time2, key)
ggplot(df1_long, aes(x=Time2, y=value)) + 
  geom_line() +
  facet_wrap( ~ key, scales = "free_y", ncol = 1, drop = T) +
  xlab("Time") + ylab("Value")
```

this gives me the time series plot for all the keys in df1_long like below - one issue with the below plot is that it removes the timestamp details in x-axis labels - I would have preferred a `hh:mm:ss` style

[image]

I have another set of similar data `df2` from another measurement which is overlapped in time with `df1` as below. How do I go about to get the time series plot for the keys in the same panel per key in the same plot - meaning for `Col01` to `Col12` the data from df1 and df2 in the same panel in a time aligned fashion.

```
text2 <- "
Time,Col01,Col02,Col03,Col04,Col05,Col06,Col07,Col08,Col09,Col10,Col11,Col12
05:17:55.601000,,,28,,12.0,23.0,2.0,3.0,142.42307692307693,122,18,2.0,
05:17:55.641000,268,5,28,-63.64,12.0,24.0,2.0,3.0,156.67857142857142,126,18,2.0,15.956
05:17:55.681000,268,5,,-64.08500000000001,,24.0,,3.0,154.0344827586207,131,18,,15.4775
05:17:55.721000,268,5,28,-63.63,9.0,19.0,3.0,4.0,135.85,133,17,0.0,15.4415
05:17:55.761000,268,5,28,-63.305,10.0,19.0,2.5,4.0,152.69565217391303,138,18,2.0,14.9695
05:17:55.801000,268,5,28,-62.59,11.0,23.0,2.0,3.0,154.89655172413794,142,18,2.0,15.525
05:17:55.841000,,,28,,12.0,23.0,2.0,3.0,132.7391304347826,146,18,2.0,
05:17:55.881000,,,28,,10.0,24.0,2.0,3.0,154.04166666666666,151,18,2.0,
05:17:55.921000,268,5,28,-62.455,12.0,23.0,2.0,3.0,139.2962962962963,153,18,2.0,15.7515
05:17:55.961000,268,5,28,-62.725,12.5,23.0,2.0,3.0,148.74074074074073,158,18,2.0,15.4405
05:17:56.001000,268,5,28,-63.269999999999996,13.0,25.0,2.0,3.0,136.91304347826087,162,18,1.0,14.9835
05:17:56.041000,,,28,,13.0,25.0,2.0,3.0,137.125,166,18,1.0,
05:17:56.081000,268,5,28,-63.66,12.0,25.0,2.0,3.0,142.67857142857142,171,18,2.0,15.919
05:17:56.121000,268,5,,-63.34,,25.0,,3.0,157.16666666666666,175,18,,15.605
05:17:56.161000,268,5,28,-63.305,12.0,23.0,2.0,3.0,144.82758620689654,179,18,2.0,15.788
05:17:56.201000,268,5,28,-62.825,11.0,24.0,2.0,3.0,142.63888888888889,183,18,2.0,15.7765
05:17:56.241000,268,5,28,-62.61,12.0,22.0,2.0,3.0,157.10344827586206,185,18,2.0,15.05
05:17:56.281000,268,5,28,-62.73,11.5,23.0,2.0,3.0,147.69230769230768,191,18,2.0,15.2765
05:17:56.321000,268,5,28,-62.78,13.0,24.0,2.0,3.0,157.66666666666666,194,18,1.0,15.383000000000001
05:17:56.361000,268,5,28,-62.58,12.5,25.0,2.0,3.0,149.5,198,18,2.0,15.358
05:17:56.401000,268,5,28,-62.64,12.0,25.0,2.0,3.0,146.0,202,18,2.0,15.994000000000002
05:17:56.441000,,,28,,11.0,22.0,2.0,3.0,159.68571428571428,205,18,2.0,
05:17:56.481000,268,5,,-62.54,,22.0,,3.0,150.08695652173913,211,18,,16.258
05:17:56.521000,268,5,,-62.555,,22.0,,3.0,154.08695652173913,213,18,,15.7555
05:17:56.561000,268,5,28,-62.620000000000005,10.0,22.0,2.0,3.0,166.6818181818182,219,18,2.0,15.1225
05:17:56.601000,268,5,28,-62.545,11.5,20.0,2.0,3.0,165.05555555555554,222,18,2.0,15.850999999999999
05:17:56.641000,268,5,28,-62.405,11.0,22.0,2.5,3.0,132.0,228,18,2.5,16.743000000000002
05:17:56.681000,268,5,28,-62.595,13.5,17.0,2.0,4.0,155.23529411764707,230,18,1.0,15.788
05:17:56.721000,268,5,28,-62.225,12.5,23.0,2.0,3.0,171.0625,234,18,0.5,15.5885
05:17:56.761000,,,28,,11.0,22.0,2.0,3.0,159.77777777777777,237,18,2.0,
05:17:56.801000,,,28,,12.0,22.0,2.0,3.0,135.5,241,18,2.0,
05:17:56.841000,,,28,,10.0,22.0,2.0,3.0,157.77272727272728,245,18,2.0,
05:17:56.881000,268,5,,-62.43,,22.0,,3.0,152.67857142857142,249,18,,16.249
05:17:56.921000,268,5,,-62.405,,22.0,,3.0,143.13333333333333,253,18,,16.463
05:17:56.961000,268,5,28,-63.05,10.5,18.0,2.5,4.0,152.86363636363637,258,18,2.0,16.5975
05:17:57.001000,,,28,,11.0,18.0,2.5,4.0,146.20833333333334,262,18,2.5,
05:17:57.041000,268,5,28,-62.88,12.0,18.0,2.0,4.0,144.3,266,18,1.0,15.937000000000001
05:17:57.081000,,,28,,10.0,23.0,2.0,3.0,184.54545454545453,270,18,2.0,
05:17:57.121000,268,5,28,-63.16,10.0,24.0,2.0,3.0,138.96296296296296,274,18,2.0,16.67
05:17:57.161000,268,5,,-63.05,,25.0,,3.0,140.63636363636363,279,18,,16.932000000000002
05:17:57.201000,268,5,,-62.735,,23.0,,3.0,177.28571428571428,281,18,,16.0465
05:17:57.241000,268,5,28,-63.010000000000005,10.0,23.0,3.0,3.0,162.88888888888889,285,18,3.0,15.940000000000001
05:17:57.281000,268,5,28,-63.17,9.5,19.0,3.0,4.0,137.66666666666666,290,18,2.5,16.336
05:17:57.321000,268,5,28,-63.2,13.0,19.0,2.0,4.0,122.22222222222223,294,18,1.0,15.9415
05:17:57.361000,268,5,28,-63.365,12.5,24.0,2.0,3.0,151.95833333333334,300,18,1.0,15.640999999999998
05:17:57.401000,268,5,28,-63.39,11.0,24.0,2.0,3.0,146.8421052631579,303,17,2.0,16.131
05:17:57.441000,268,5,28,-63.51,11.0,24.0,2.0,3.0,157.58333333333334,307,18,2.0,16.482
05:17:57.481000,268,5,28,-63.71,12.5,23.0,2.0,3.0,162.41666666666666,309,18,2.0,15.562000000000001
05:17:57.521000,,,28,,12.0,24.0,2.0,3.0,170.35,313,18,2.0,
05:17:57.561000,268,5,,-63.83,,24.0,,3.0,141.23809523809524,317,18,,15.956
05:17:57.601000,268,5,28,-63.69,13.0,25.0,2.0,3.0,160.03225806451613,323,18,1.0,16.235
05:17:57.641000,268,5,28,-63.815,11.5,25.0,2.5,3.0,153.07692307692307,328,16,2.5,15.858
05:17:57.681000,268,5,28,-63.81,12.5,19.0,2.0,4.0,118.30434782608695,332,18,2.0,15.575499999999998
05:17:57.721000,268,5,28,-63.58,12.0,24.0,2.0,3.0,159.57692307692307,334,18,1.0,15.8615
05:17:57.761000,268,5,28,-63.71,11.5,24.0,2.0,3.0,138.23076923076923,338,18,2.0,16.495
05:17:57.801000,268,5,28,-63.88,12.5,24.0,2.0,3.0,138.9375,342,18,1.5,15.195
05:17:57.841000,,,28,,11.5,24.0,2.0,3.0,161.375,347,18,1.5,
05:17:57.881000,268,5,,-64.04,,25.0,,3.0,142.6,351,18,,15.945
05:17:57.921000,268,5,,-64.08500000000001,,18.0,,4.0,147.44444444444446,353,18,,15.9215
05:17:57.961000,268,5,28,-64.095,10.0,24.0,3.0,3.0,152.40740740740742,357,18,3.0,15.3915
05:17:58.001000,268,5,28,-64.16,10.0,18.0,3.0,4.0,157.88888888888889,364,18,3.0,15.120999999999999
05:17:58.041000,,,,,,18.0,,4.0,137.0,364,18,,
05:17:58.081000,268,5,28,-64.19,12.0,24.0,2.0,3.0,138.0,370,18,0.0,16.262
05:17:58.121000,268,5,28,-64.16,10.0,24.0,3.0,3.0,142.92307692307693,375,18,3.0,16.129
05:17:58.161000,268,5,28,-64.32,13.0,18.0,2.0,4.0,142.125,380,18,2.0,14.849
05:17:58.201000,,,28,,10.0,23.0,3.0,3.0,148.0909090909091,384,18,3.0,
05:17:58.241000,268,5,28,-64.065,13.0,18.0,2.0,4.0,162.41666666666666,385,18,2.0,15.9685
05:17:58.281000,,,28,,12.0,24.0,2.0,3.0,139.0,389,18,2.0,
05:17:58.321000,268,5,28,-64.32499999999999,13.0,24.0,2.0,3.0,155.15,396,18,2.0,15.324
05:17:58.361000,,,,,,24.0,,3.0,156.25,397,15,,
05:17:58.401000,268,5,28,-63.88,10.0,24.0,2.0,3.0,150.8,402,13,2.0,16.375999999999998
05:17:58.441000,,,,,,23.0,,3.0,133.125,407,16,,
05:17:58.481000,268,5,28,-64.35,13.0,23.0,2.0,3.0,142.72727272727272,412,18,2.0,14.857999999999999
05:17:58.521000,268,5,28,-64.41,10.0,24.0,3.0,3.0,141.45454545454547,416,18,2.0,15.761
05:17:58.561000,,,,,,,,,,,,,
05:17:58.601000,268,5,28,-63.66,12.0,24.0,2.0,3.0,138.25,421,15,2.0,15.546
05:17:58.641000,268,5,28,-64.26,13.0,25.0,2.0,3.0,130.86666666666667,427,18,0.0,15.74
05:17:58.681000,268,5,28,-63.91,12.0,24.0,2.0,3.0,170.2941176470588,430,18,2.0,15.495999999999999
05:17:58.721000,268,5,28,-64.2,10.0,24.5,2.0,3.0,152.9375,434,18,2.0,15.914000000000001
05:17:58.761000,268,5,28,-64.63,10.0,25.0,2.0,3.0,144.72222222222223,438,18,2.0,14.445
05:17:58.801000,268,5,28,-63.87,12.0,24.0,2.0,3.0,166.6,443,18,1.0,15.43
05:17:58.841000,,,,,,,,,,,,,
05:17:58.881000,268,5,28,-63.82,12.0,16.0,2.0,4.0,167.15384615384616,450,18,2.0,15.331
05:17:58.921000,268,5,28,-64.65,13.0,17.0,2.0,4.0,160.4,453,18,0.0,14.524000000000001
05:17:58.961000,,,,,,24.0,,3.0,140.91666666666666,459,18,,
05:17:59.001000,268,5,,-64.52,,25.0,,3.0,171.0,463,18,,15.91
05:17:59.041000,,,28,,12.0,24.0,2.0,3.0,139.5,466,18,2.0,
05:17:59.081000,268,5,28,-63.68,12.0,23.0,2.0,3.0,184.66666666666666,470,18,2.0,15.328
05:17:59.121000,268,5,28,-62.85,12.5,24.0,2.0,3.0,165.25925925925927,474,18,2.0,16.712
05:17:59.161000,,,,,,23.0,,3.0,163.9375,477,18,,
05:17:59.201000,268,5,28,-63.81,13.0,16.0,2.0,4.0,186.05555555555554,481,18,0.0,16.35
05:17:59.241000,268,5,28,-63.55,10.0,18.0,3.0,4.0,130.7391304347826,487,18,3.0,15.17
05:17:59.281000,268,5,28,-63.17,13.0,18.0,2.0,4.0,144.4,492,7,2.0,14.825999999999999
"

df2 <- read.table(textConnection(text2), sep=",", header = T)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all your df2 seems to have one extra column.

With that fixed I can combine both dataframes with `bind_rows`. I gave each a different `dat` number, so I can distinquish both lines in the plot.

I fixed the time format, by setting `date_labels` in `scale_x_datetime`

```
df1_long <- df1 %>%
  mutate(Time = as.POSIXct(Time, format ="%H:%M:%OS" )) %>%
  gather(key, value, -Time) %>%
  mutate(dat = 1)

df2_long <- df2 %>%
  mutate(Time = as.POSIXct(Time, format ="%H:%M:%OS" )) %>%
  gather(key, value, -Time) %>%
  mutate(dat = 2)

df1_long %>%
  bind_rows(df2_long) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=Time, y=value, color = factor(dat))) + 
  geom_line() +
  facet_wrap( ~ key, scales = "free_y", ncol = 1, drop = T) +
  scale_x_datetime(date_labels  = "%H:%M:%OS") +
  xlab("Time") + ylab("Value")
```

result of one facet:
[image]